# Closed-form solution for capacitor charged with current source and discharged through resistor

Tags: circuit-analysis

It has been ages since I last did circuit analysis by hand and I am stuck with a simple circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fc7yjO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am looking for the closed-form solution of the voltage at node V as a function of time, in response to a step-function input of I. I.e. I = 0 for t<0 and I = I for t>=0.

I am stuck with what seems to be a non-separable integration problem:

C*dV/dt + (V-V1)/R = I

Can somebody help me with this integration? Or can this only be solved numerically?

Comment: Both V1 and I are step inputs?

Comment: Have you tried the Laplace transform method ?

Comment: @user215805 V1 is constant

Comment: @AJN I solved it with I = dQ/dt and V=Q/c. Thanks for the hint though.

Comment: @relayman357 Thanks for your answer. You were right that my solution was wrong. I deleted it from the question to avoid confusing readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it via Laplace (as AJN recommends above).

The circuit in Laplace,

[image]

Using superposition to find voltage, **V(s)**, from the upper node to reference:

the contribution from the current source will be,

$$V^ʹ(s)=\frac{I}{s}(\frac{\frac{R}{sC}}{R+\frac{1}{sC}})  $$

the contribution from the capacitor initial voltage (assuming charged to V1 prior to t = 0) will be,

$$V^{ʹʹ}(s)=\frac{V1}{s}(\frac{R}{R+\frac{1}{sC}})  $$

the contribution from the voltage source will be,

$$V^{ʹʹʹ}(s)=\frac{V1}{s}(\frac{\frac{1}{sC}}{R+\frac{1}{sC}})  $$

So,
$$V(s)=V^{ʹ}(s)+V^{ʹʹ}(s)+V^{ʹʹʹ}(s)$$

Inverse Laplace transform,

$$v(t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{I}{s}(\frac{\frac{R}{sC}}{R+\frac{1}{sC}})]+\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{V1}{s}(\frac{R}{R+\frac{1}{sC}})]+\mathcal{L}^{-1}[\frac{V1}{s}(\frac{\frac{1}{sC}}{R+\frac{1}{sC}})]$$

$$v(t) = IR(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})+V1e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}+V1(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}) $$

Which simplifies to,
$$v(t) = IR(1-e^{\frac{-t}{RC}})+V1$$

I plugged in R = 2Ω, C = 100µF (charged to 12V at t = 0), I = 5A, and V1 = 12V and the above solution plots as,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your equation

$$\small C\frac{dV}{dt}+\frac{V}{R}=I+\frac{V_1 }{R} $$

Divide through by \$\small C\$

$$\small \frac{dV}{dt}+\frac{V}{RC}=\frac{I}{C}+\frac{V_1 }{RC} $$

The right hand side is a constant, so solve the first order differential equation via the integrating factor method, with initial condition \$\small V(0)=V_1 \$